# Edit already open word file

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

Out of my application, the user opens a letter with attachments. These attachments are not shown and are printed in the background together with the other file.

Now my problem is, that during this background print, I need to put a barcode on it. I already have a working solution which is:
Create a temp. copy, put barcode on in, print, delete temp. copy.

I can't just save the attachment with the barcode, as with every print a new barcode is put on it.
Also just try to put the barcode on the in the background open word file doesn't work because it's already opened and therefore blocked.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Sorry for the unclear question. The barcode is put on the attachments, which are word files as well. They are dotx files and are forms for the user to fill out later after print. These dotx files can be attachments for different letters and therefore I can't just save the attachment with the barcode because used with a different letter, a new barcode will be printed on it.

Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: You need to put barcode where, on word doc or attachments? Can you please make your question clear. And specify what are these attachments?

Comment: How do you get the file? If they open the letter (wild guess: you mean "email"?) out of your app, how do you know they opened it and have to print the attachtments? I'm thinking of opening the file on your app, modify it in-memory and print it.

Comment: My application is a template manager with which the user can create different templates so he doesn't need to rewrite them over and over again each time he uses it. They open the letter by a simple click on a "Test template" button. This opens a word instance with all the parameters loaded. I also made a word addon (ribbon) and when the user clicks print, it automatically prints the attached files in the background as well